# Можно ли в с++ подписаться на события сокета

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, сокет, winsock

Делаю игру для windows по локальной сети на с++ с помощью сокетов. Очевидно, клиент должен реагировать вызовом метода на сообщение от сервера. Пока встретила только функцию send, передающую строки, и первая мысль была сделать это через switch case. Есть ли другие варианты, можно в с++ подписаться на события сокета?

Comment: А какие события вас интересуют? Вообще, есть статья Криса Касперски по сокетам, поищите там.

Comment: игра шахматы, клиент посылает запрос на ход, сервер его обрабатывает и вызывает перерисовку экрана клиента. Я прочитала статью, так вот там клиент и сервер обмениваются строками

Comment: Так нужны ли Вам тогда события сокета ? Как это реализовано у Вас, можно посмотреть на исходный код ?

Comment: я пока только обдумываю, как это сделать.

Comment: Должно быть как-то так: есть класс Message, у него есть холдеры, с каждым действием (например, начать партию, сделать ход, объявить результаты и т.д.) должен быть ассоциирован определенный тип сообщения - т.е. в каждом сообщении в одном из холдеров вы передаете этот тип (скажем, mtStartGame, mtMoveFigure, mtShowResults), на сервере у Вас должен быть класс, напичканный методами для обработки каждого типа сообщений, создаете map типа 'тип_сообщения - указатель на член класса(хэндлер)', ну и все - пришло сообщение, сокет его прочитал, тип мессаги известен - срабатывает хэндлер.

Comment: На стороне клиента происходит событие, как о нем узнает сервер? получается нужно функцией send послать серверу тип сообщения в виде строки  (mtMoveFigure, mtShowResults). Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Не обязательно строки. Можно создать enum, и перечислить в нем все типы сообщений. Так что передаваться будет unsigned int, это проще. Что касается сообщений от клиента к серверу - все аналогично, отправляете мессагу серверу, в ней лежит тип, сервер получает сообщение, определяет его тип, вызывает соответствующий хэндлер.

Comment: а какая функция будет передавать int ?

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял, видимо потому, что и Вы не поняли меня. Комментарий я оформлю в виде ответа.

Comment: вопрос в том, как послать сообщение от клиента серверу  и наоборот?

Comment: Нужно его сначала сеарилизовать - а потом уже слать. Т.е. в классе ```Message``` у Вас должно быть два метода, ```read``` и ```write```, которые бы содержимое класса отправляли в ```std::ofstream&``` и читали с ```std::ifstream&```.

Comment: То есть через файл?

Comment: Это для удобства, так - используйте ```std::stringstream```. Создали std::stringstream из содержимого буфера сокета, отправили на десериализацию. И по-хорошему, должна у Вас быть фабрика, которая из такого stream'а создает инстанс мессаги. Потому как разные сообщения ~ разные размеры/кол-во холдеров и т.д.